# Recursive bubble sort Python doesn't work compared to R

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new in Python. Same code works well on R, but I can't understand why it doesn't work in Python...

Python:

```
#swap pair
def swap_pair(xpair):
    if xpair[0] > xpair[1]:
        xpair.reverse()
    else:
        xpair
    return xpair

#swap_pass
def swap_pass(xlist):
    for i in range(0,len(xlist)-1):
        xlist[i:i+2] = swap_pair(xlist[i:i+2])
    return xlist

def bubble_sort(data):
    newdata = swap_pass(data)
    if data == newdata:
        return(newdata)
    else:
        return bubble_sort(newdata)

test = [100,6,5,3,2,1]
bubble_sort(test)
```

> Out: [6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 100]

Here is same code in R which works well:

```
swap_if_larger = function(pair) {
  if( pair[1] > pair[2] )
    return(rev(pair)) else
      return(pair)
}

swap_pass = function(vec) { 
  for(i in seq(1, length(vec)-1)) { 
    vec[i:(i+1)] = swap_if_larger(vec[i:(i+1)]) 
  }
  return(vec)
}

bubble_sort = function(vec) {
  new_vec = swap_pass(vec)
  if( isTRUE(all.equal(new_vec, vec)) ) { 
    return(new_vec) 
  } else {
    return(bubble_sort(new_vec))
  }
}

test = c(100,6,5,3,2,1)
bubble_sort(test)
```

> > bubble_sort(test)
> >
> > [1]   1   2   3   5   6 100

Can you help here?

Comment: Side-note: Implementing bubble sort recursively is a really bad idea in Python. Python imposes a default stack limit of 1000, so this will explode due to excessive recursion for lists of any real size. Granted, implementing any sort of sort in Python for anything other than learning purposes is a bad idea; `sorted`/`list.sort` is just better than any general purpose sorting algorithm you could implement by virtue of being implemented in C on CPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `swap_pass` is mutating `data` in place and returning it. So in `bubble_sort`, both `data` and `new_data` are references to the *same* `list`. If you want to avoid that, copy when you call, so you actually have two different `list`s:

```
def bubble_sort(data):
    newdata = swap_pass(data[:])  # Empty slice copies data before passing to swap_pass
    if data == newdata:
        return(newdata)
    else:
        return bubble_sort(newdata)
```

Alternatively, make `swap_pass` do the copy for you, so callers don't need to think about it (this is generally the Pythonic way to do it; Python functions *either* mutate the argument and return nothing *or* return a new value and leave the argument unchanged, they don't mutate *and* return):

```
def swap_pass(xlist):
    xlist = xlist[:]  # Add shallow copy before doing work
    for i in range(0,len(xlist)-1):
        xlist[i:i+2] = swap_pair(xlist[i:i+2])
    return xlist
```